# Does a Dropbox shared folder occupy storage space on all accounts?

Tags: dropbox, online-storage

I have to share photos and video of an event with a number of friends, and I'm considering to use Dropbox for this purpose.

Since the initial storage space offered by this service is not really that big, I'd like to know if a shared folder occupy space even in the accounts of the "receivers" and not only in the "sharer" one.

*Example:*

**"A"** creates a folder whose total size is, let's say, 200 MB; the total storage space of **"A"** is of course reduced by 200 MB; if **"A"** shares this folder with **"B"**, **"C"** and **"D"**, even their total storage space is reduced accordingly, or the folder is considered to be "owned" only by **"A"**, and only his account is affected?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the shared folder/files will take up space in everyone's account who has access to it.

From [Dropbox's Help Centre](https://www.dropbox.com/help/space/shared-folder-count-against-storage):

> The size of a shared folder will be counted against the quota of every member of that folder, unless each person is on the same Dropbox Business team.

Comment: For another option, Box.com is a similar service to Dropbox, but will only count the file size of shared files against the sharer's quota.

Answer (score 2):

yes, Dropbox expects you to pay to view someone else's shared folder that they've already paid for.

Google Drive doesn't do this. only the owner of the shared folder pays for that storage.